# Has Belwin Mills improved their bookbinding?

Tags: sheet-music, books, publishing

I'm sitting here looking at three separate books of sheet music for piano published as Kalmus Piano Series by Belwin-Mills. You know the ones; they have a cover in a solid color (often red or orange) with a handwritten score of Bach's Sinfonia #15 superimposed in white ink, and the actual title of the score in black on top of all that.

[image: A typical cover]

All of them have disintegrated into little pamphlets of music. Most of my equally old scores by different publishers are still intact.

I'm wondering whether I should replace them with new copies or seek alternative editions. Will newer ones fall apart too?

Comment: I have a hard time imagining anyone here knowing, but have you tried asking them directly?

Comment: (Also, sometimes I've taken a big unwieldy volume, sliced off its binding, and taken it to Kinkos to be spiral-bound so now it lies flat. I started the habit when a big glue-bound paperback volume disintegrated, but now sometimes do it preventatively.)

Comment: I do not know the ones, but I’m seriously confused why they would put Bach on the cover for a Beethoven score ...

Comment: @Lazy so all the covers look the same.

Comment: "You know the ones"? Are you sure they're a thing the world over? Many of us have never been to your continent (regardless which one it is).

Comment: @Divizna true enough, but by reading this description you can infer that these editions are well known by at least some people in at least some part of the world.

Answer (score 2):

Belwin-Mills no longer exists as such. Their catalog is now owned by Alfred Music, which

> continues to publish music with the Kalmus name under the Kalmus Classic Series imprint, the vast majority consisting of inexpensive reprints of old editions now in the public domain. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_F._Kalmus#Legacy))

Even with better binding, these are cheap and potentially unreliable (i.e., error prone). If possible, the investment in higher quality scores would be worthwhile. Bärenreiter and Henle being top choices.

However, the latter are expensive. I have had good experiences with Alfred scores generally, but can't speak specifically to their Kalmus publications. These scores are also available from publishers like Peters, which similarly produces reprints of other editions, and Dover.

The same source editions can also be printed for free from websites like [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Main_Page) and put in a three ring-binder (I recommend using plastic sheet protectors) or a dedicated music folder like the one [produced by Cranbury](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08R8RB1KF).

Comment: "potentially unreliable (i.e., error prone)": for the most part this arises because the business model is to publish reproductions of older editions whose copyright protection has expired.  These older editions are more likely to have errors because they are less likely to benefit from the latest musicological research.  A problem with plastic sheet protectors is that they make it difficult to use a pencil.  If one is printing music for use in rehearsal it may be better to invest in heavier paper.

Comment: @phoog Follow the link to the Cranbury folder. It's designed specifically for music, and the plastic area comprises two strips covering the top and bottom of the page, allowing for note taking.

Comment: Nice.  I _had_ followed the link, but hadn't noticed that detail.